# Paste a feature from an existing shapefile into a row with null geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

If I have an existing row in my PostGIS database with NULL geometry, is it possible to select a feature from another layer in QGIS, and paste that into the empty geometry column for the PostGIS row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Import the Shapefile that contains the feature into `PostGIS` (keeping them in the same `SRIDs`), you can use [`shp1pgsql`](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg) or [`pgShapeLoader`](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/186-PostGIS-2.0.0-Shapefile-GUI-Loader-and-Exporter.html)
- Select the geometry of the feature (Apply a filter, button in the top panel near the SQL query button, select the feature you want to copy the geometry of)
  [image]
- Double click the geometry, copy it and then paste it in the NULL geometry column.
  [image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Where am I doing the copying and pasting? Within QGIS?  I don't see geometry columns in QGIS. I can see them in the DB Manager, but cannot copy/paste.  Maybe I could ask the question in a more general way: what is the best way to move a single feature from a shapefile to a PostgreS table -- especially in a case where the table schema of the shapefile doesn't exactly match that of the PostgreS table?

Comment: You'll copy and paste them in PostGIS, you'll have to move the shapefile to PostGIS first